# Is it possible to upload to web service from HTML 5

Tags: web-services, html

I have a large file upload written in Silverlight, i open the file and send chunks to a asmx web service which in turn concatenates the file chunks and creates the file. I would like to change this upload method from Silverlight to HTML 5 if possible. But is it even possible to chunk up the file in HTML 5 upload and send chunks to a web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its possible to send multipart forms (a.k.a file uploads) but don't try to implement it from scratch. You would need iframe workaround for older browsers.

Try out this library: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Also see this answer: [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

[Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is how JavaScript communicates with a server.

[here is a tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-javascript.php)